# HTML/CSS double nav in the left bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with my new website, the nav appears twice, once where it suppose to be and the second time it appears is in the left bottom corner.
it creates a new div that i don't know where it comes from

I think an example well help you understand it better:

i tried uploading it to jsfiddle so you can see it better but i had troubles so i uploaded it to a free web hosting: https://kartis.000webhostapp.com/contact.php
**you can see the problem in the left bottom corner.**

HTML:

```
<head>
        <title>kartiSell</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Yoav Levy">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Yoav Levy">
        <meta name="author" content="Yoav Levy">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
        <meta name="revisit-after" content="1 day">
        <meta name="expires" content="Wed, 21 Feb 2080 21:18:48 GMT">
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/css.css" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/ico.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="images/ico.png" sizes="192x192" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <div class="inner">
                    <a href="index.html" class="logo"></a>
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                        <a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
                        <a href="signup.php">Sign up</a>
                        <a href="sell.php">SELL</a>
                        <a href="contact.php">Contact us</a>
                    </nav>

                </div>

            </header>
            <!-- Sells -->
<div id=content>

            safdsfasdf


</div>
        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>



</div></body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
@-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
body {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 6em;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
     header { position: absolute; }

}
#header {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #d5d5d5;
    cursor: default;
    height: 85px;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 5em;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: right;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10001;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #c0c0c0;
}

    #header .inner {
        width:100%;
        height:inherit;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 1500px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: -10px;

    }

        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

            #header .inner {
                max-width: 100%;
                width: 100%;

            }
            #nav {
                margin-top: 1em;
        }

        }

    #header .logo {
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: inherit;
        margin: -2px;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        padding: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:341px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        background-image: url('/images/logo.png');
    }

        #header .logo:hover {
            background-image: url('/images/logohover.png');
        }

    #header a {
        -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
        transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 5em;
        margin-right:10px;
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: .85em;
        margin-top: 0em;
    }

        #header a:hover {
            color: #ff001e;
        }


        @media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
            #nav {
                margin-top: 1em;
        }
            #header a {
                padding: 0 0.5em;
            }
        }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    #header {
        min-width: 320px;

    }
}
#nav {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

    #nav {
        margin-top: 1em;
        display: none;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    #nav {
        margin-top: 1em;
}

}
```

picture: https://ibb.co/kM52BF

Comment: I only see it at the bottom left. Nowhere else.

Comment: you've got a div with id `navPanel` at the end of your dom, check in your source

Comment: @Rob you don't see it at the top? near the logo?

Comment: @ImmortalDude the thing is i dont! i posted here the html look i dont have this div i dont get what the hell is going on

Comment: Nope. Not at all in either Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @Rob https://ibb.co/kM52BF

Comment: The nav at the top disappears when the browser width is made thinner. That's why I didn't see it.

Comment: Check your main.js file, on line 48, you've added this div with appendTo to your html. If it's for responsive purpose and should be visible on small devices, give it proper visibility or display with css.

Comment: @Rob I know its invisible for mobile surfing purposes, but if ur on full screen u can see it right?

Comment: Yes, as I said.

Comment: @Rob if we'r already chatting, can you help me put this navpanel appear on the right top corner when the normal nav disappears... (with a font awesome toggle icon)

Answer (score 1):

I think this part of your code in main.js is causing this problem:

```
        // Navigation Panel Toggle.
            $('<a href="#navPanel" class="navPanelToggle"></a>')
                .appendTo($body);

        // Navigation Panel.
            $(
                '<div id="navPanel">' +
                    $('#nav').html() +
                    '<a href="#navPanel" class="close"></a>' +
                '</div>'
            )
                .appendTo($body)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's true, and if i want to make the navpanel visible only when the width is minimized to a mobile phone resolution how can i do it ? also i want it to appear on the top right corrner like the normal one but with font awosme toggle. please help

Comment: Hi, you can take a look at CSS media queries to accomplish that. Also, you can refer http://navnav.co/ to check how to implement the nav toggle that you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Give display:none !important to the particular id:

```
#navPanel
{
display:none !important;
}
```

Please check it will affect anywhere in the webpages.

Comment: omg, it worked! i tried it already before but i didn't include the !important. but i still don't understand why this navpanel div appeared i didn't included it in the code

Comment: @yoash Don't do that. It's a hack at best. Fix your code. Don't hack it.

Comment: and why without the !important it doesn't work?  thank you

Comment: check your javascript file @yoash

Answer (score -1):

Think the problem is with the js in you page. Please remove the lines(49-63) from main.js

Hope this will fix the issue